# Stored Procedure Results and Ad-Hoc Query Results in Single Request?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, sqldatareader

I'm using plain ADO.NET to returns results from my SQL Server database.

I have a control that requires two sets of results. To make the control efficient, my plan was to send two queries in a single request to avoid multiple trips to the database, and use `SqlDataReader.NextResult()` to access the second set of results.

However, looking at the code, I see the first query is actually calling a stored procedure.

Is there any way to use ADO.NET to request the results from both a stored procedure and an ad-hoc query in a single request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, and exactly in the way you suggest.  Set CommandType to Text, and CommandText to:

```
exec YourProcedure;
select * from YourTable;
```

You can use `NextResult` two move to the next resultset.

Comment: Oh, cool. Guess I hadn't used `EXEC` this way before. Thanks!